# SQL to retrieve most up to date rows

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Must be a fairly common task, but I can't find an elegant way to do it.

Table:

```
Id  
testdate  
partid  
testid
```

The same part may undergo the same test multiple times. I want the most recent results from all test done on all parts in (partlist).

```
SELECT max(testdate) 
FROM table 
WHERE partid IN (partlist) 
GROUP BY testid, partid
```

Would almost do the job, except that it doesn't give me the needed id field. I could first select the correct date and then selecting the id field using testdate, partid and testid in the WHERE clause, but that is kind of ugly.

There must be a nicer way of doing this?

I'm willing to give up the partlist and get data for only one part at a time, if needed.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I use ms sql, but any SQL should be good enough to answer the question. If it is not some very obscure function translation to your local dialect is usually easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's elegant.  And then there's efficient.  In terms of elegance, the `row_number()` function can help.

In terms of efficiency, the `not exists` approach seems to work well in many databases:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE partid IN (partlist) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table t2
                  WHERE t2.testid = t.testid and t2.partid = t.partid and
                        t2.testdate > t.testdate
                 );
```

It is saying:  "Get me all rows from the table where there is not another row with the same `testid` and `partid` but with a larger `testdate`."

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! Was put-off for a second by the SELECT 1 FROM ... part. But now I get it, its just select anything, a dummy, and if the WHERE clause is not fulfilled it won't get any results, not even "1". (Just in case someone else has the same problem as I had)

Comment: Secondly, I'm amazed it is efficient. Now we check the whole table again and again for each row of that table? But it worked on my 1.4 TB table, so it is not all that bad.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select id, 
       max_testdate,
       partid,
       testid
from (
  select Id,
         testdate,
         max(testdate) over (partition by testid, partid) as max_testdate
         partid  
         testid
  from the_table
) t
where testdate = max_testdate
```

Comment: This works too actually. I had to wrap it in an extra "SELECT * FROM (..)" though, to prevent for the error "Invalid column name 'max_testdate'" in ms sql. Thanks for introducing me to the OVER (PARTITION BY ..) clause.